# Water Pressure Change in sink after installing Fill Valve in Toilet

Tags: plumbing, toilet, sink, water-pressure

In my master bathroom I recently changed the fill valve and flapper as it was constantly running and having issues. The good news is that my toilet works as expected and that issue is resolved. The interesting development is that the sink that is adjacent to the toilet now has noticeably stronger water pressure. Is this something I should be concerned about? Anything I need to adjust as a result?

Thank you!

Comment: That is expected.  A house water system has one source of pressure, That pressure comes out of one open faucet/toilet.  If more than faucet is open at the same time, the pressure is reduced.  If second open faucet is closed the pressure comes back to normal.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the pressure is *always* stronger. Not just when flushing...

Comment: Flushing should reduce the pressure some if using the sink at the same time.  It is when then toilet finishes filling up, the pressure should come back to normal.  Does the pressure seem normal to what it was before the toilet problem, or does it seem very high?  It might be a second problem with a pressure regulator valve if very high(above 80 pounds).

Comment: The pressure is definitely more than it was before. I wouldn't say it's outrageous, just more than the sort of dribble that we used to have. What is the pressure regulator? Is that on the sink or the toilet?

Comment: Regulator if you have one should be near where the water comes into the house.  They are used when city/town pressure is high.  House plumbing should be below 80#

Comment: If the flush valve was leaking badly, water was going down the drain, lowering pressure in the whole system, and wasting *huge* amounts of water. It's **good** that you fixed the issue, but surprising it had gotten so bad as to lower water pressure!

Comment: Well the interesting thing is that the leaking water only started maybe a week ago. We mitigated by shutting off the water in between flushes to avoid wasting. But the new water pressure in the *sink* is stronger than ever. both when it was working prior or broken. 

Is there a way to test the pressure, easily? I honestly don't think it's insane but I am curious what it is.